# Forms em Django, ajuda?

Tags: python, django

Há algum modo de trabalhar com *forms* de modo prático em Django?

A questão é que estou criando um site por conta própria e como já conhecia Python, então decidi usar Django. "Tudo" estava bem, até eu tentar criar uma *form* de cadastro para o tal site. Já vi diversos tutoriais no YouTube e não consigo fazer o bendito *form* e, quando consigo, não consigo o integrar no CSS.

O fato que enquanto fazia o *front* do site eu criei esse *form*:

```html
<form method="post">
  <label class="#">Nome completo:</label>
  <input class="#" type="text" name="">
  <div class=#></div>
  <label class="#">Email:</label>
  <input class="#" type="text" name="">
  <div style="#"></div>
  <label class="#">Senha:</label>
  <input class="#" type="password" name="" autocomplete="off">
  <div style="#"></div>
  <label class="#">Confirmar senha:</label>
  <input class="#" type="password" name="" autocomplete="off">
  <div style="#"></div>
  <label class="#">País:</label>
  <input class="#" type="text" name="">
  <div style="#"></div>
  <label class="#">Cidade:</label>
  <input class="#" type="text" name="">
  <div style="#"></div>
  <label class="#">Data de Nascimento:</label>
  <input class=# type="text" name="">
  <div style="#"></div>
  <input style="#" type="submit" value="Confirmar cadastro" id="cadastrar" name="cadastrar">
</form>
```

A minha dúvida é: Há alguma forme de eu criar uma DB com os respectivos campos e dizer basicamente

```
"Nome completo" == Nome,
"Cidade" == cidade
    ...
def save(): #Função pra salvar na DB
```

Comment: O *model* não faz exatamente isso? E o Django possui ferramentas para trabalhar com [formulários](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django).

Comment: Django Forms faz basicamente isso